# Undefined index error referencing PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I'm getting an error whilst trying to iterate some data and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  This is the format of the data I have returned from an API request:

```
Array
(
    [search-results] => Array
        (
            [entry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [author] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [authname] => Griffin J.
                                            [surname] => Griffin
                                            [initials] => J.M.
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [authname] => Williams D.
                                            [surname] => Williams
                                            [initials] => D.H.
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        ( ...etc...
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

For reference the above data printout is from `$eachJson` in the code below.

I can only do an API request to get 100 results at a time, so I set up a `for` loop to perform the search 100 times, then next 100 etc.  As there are multiple `author`s per record, I set up a `foreach` loop to iterate the authors and this is where I'm getting the error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: author in C:\xampp\htdocs\academic_intelligence\public\ScopusTest.php on line 42

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\academic_intelligence\public\ScopusTest.php on line 42
```

Here's the code:

```
$apiKey = "&apiKey=c2cb86c3a511ed34dd6f03f481c637c1";
$search1 = urlencode("badgers");
$search2 = urlencode(" OR weasels");
$start = 0;
$scopusData = [];
// create an array to represent citation values to ignore, i.e. not interested
// in any publications with less than 4 citations
$ignore = array(0, 1, 2, 3);

// set processing time for browser before timeout
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
// override default PHP memory limit
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

// REST HTTP GET Request searching for people associated with keywords (term)
$searchLink = "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=KEY(" . $search1 . $search2 . ")" . $apiKey . "&sort=citedby-count&count=100&start=" . $start . "&view=complete";

// save results to a variable
$searchResponse = file_get_contents($searchLink);

// convert JSON to PHP variable
$searchJson = json_decode($searchResponse, true);

// get total number of results for query to know when to stop iterating data
$total = $searchJson['search-results']['opensearch:totalResults'];

// iterate data loading next 200 results (max) each time and adding new results to array
for ($i = $start; $i <= $total; $i+=100) {
    // REST HTTP GET Request searching for people associated with keywords (term)
    $eachLink = "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=KEY(" . $search1 . $search2 . ")" . $apiKey . "&sort=citedby-count&count=100&start=" . $i . "&view=complete";

    // save results to a variable
    $eachResponse = file_get_contents($eachLink);

    $eachJson = json_decode($eachResponse, true);

    foreach ($eachJson['search-results']['entry'] as $record) {
        // array to store authors
        $authors = [];
        foreach ($record['author'] as $thisAuthor) { // **LINE 42**
            // push initials and surname to array
            array_push($authors, ($thisAuthor['initials'] . $thisAuthor['surname']));
        };
        // scopus ID
        $scopusID = $record['dc:identifier'];
        // paper title
        $title = $record['dc:title'];
        // date
        $date = substr($record['prism:coverDate'], 0, 4);
        // citations, if less than 4 then break out of iteration
        if (!in_array(($cites = $record['citedby-count']), $ignore)) {
            $cites = $record['citedby-count'];
        } else {
            break 2;
        }

        $thisData = [
                        "authors" => $authors,
                        "ID"      => $scopusID,
                        "title"   => $title,
                        "date"    => $date,
                        "cites"   => $cites
        ];

        array_push($scopusData, $thisData);
    }
};

// need to replace single quotes to avoid char escape
for ($i = 0; $i < count($scopusData); $i++) {
    foreach ($scopusData[$i]['authors'] as &$edit) {
        $edit = str_replace("'", "", $edit);
    };
    $scopusData[$i]['title'] = str_replace("'", "", $scopusData[$i]['title']);
};
```

I've highlighted line 42 which is causing the error.  This must be something straightforward but it's been a long day and I can't figure out the problem!  I still get the correct data at the end, the final array `scopusData` includes all the authors taken from that faulty `foreach` loop so it seems strange that I'm getting the error.

Comment: Are you *sure* that each record contains an `author` element? Maybe you should add an `ifset($record['author'])` ahead of the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: @Simba Oh man, okay, I'm an idiot - it's been a long day!  Surrounded the `foreach` loop with an `isset($record['author']` and it works okay now.  If you post that as an answer I'll click 'accept this answer' or whatever it is... thanks!

Comment: Heh, yep, I know that long day feeling very well. I've re-posted my comment as an answer for you.  :)

Comment: I'm gonna hope that apiKey isn't real or important.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yeah this is just a prototype, the API key isn't important, just a temporary one for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that each record contains an author element?

Maybe you should add an ifset($record['author']) ahead of the foreach() loop.

<sup>*(re-posted comment as an answer as OP's request)*</sup>